# What kind of loop do I use for reading a file?

Tags: c++, file, loops

In a hypothetical scenario, I don't know how many items are the file. What kind of a loop would I use to read the items in the file until the file ends? Code I'm currently working with is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    ifstream inputFile;
    int num;

    inputFile.open("TenNos.txt");
    cout << "Reading data from the file. \n";
    inputFile >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Use a while as you don't know how many iterations will occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (inputFile >> num)
{
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Will read and print `int`s from a file until it finds something that isn't an `int`, the file ends, the file isn't open, or the file is rendered unreadable for any number of other reasons.

Inspecting the [various state flags documented here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) will help you determine why the reading stopped.

[More in std::istream in general](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream). And a page on [operator bool explaining how and `while (inputFile >> num)` works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

If, after an error is detected, you want to clean up and continue, make sure [you read `clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Answer (score 1):

you should add fstream to be able to read files then use a while loop which reads the content of the file until the end.

```
#include <fstream>  // for files
#include <iostream> // printing on screen by default

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    int num;

    inputFile.open("TenNos.txt");
    cout << "Reading data from the file. \n";

    while(inputFile >> num)
        cout << num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 what about if opening fails?

Comment: Then the stream is not readable and `while(inputFile >> num)` doesn't enter.

Comment: oh yes I didn't notice that! thanx